# Ubuntu 13.04 no sound from VIA VT8233... 12.04 was the same

Tags: via

M/B has sound jacks as per usual BUT VGA card has a HDMI port, does this complicate things ?

Comment: There shouldnt be any complication there, not to say there isn't.
have a look at the login page of lightdm, and check to see if sound is muted. (upper right corner, has volume applet) Unmute if muted.

Comment: Thanks jOh but I have no idea what you mean by that...login page of lightdm what is that ?

Comment: OK I found something on that at the software centre...If I cannot work it out I'll give you another hoy...thanks

Comment: OK so far I have this response to lightdm --test-mode :- Running inside an X server requires Xephyr to be installed but it cannot be found.  Please install it or update your PATH environment variable.(lightdm can only be run as root) so not sure about that jOh

Comment: lightdm is the desktop isn't it ? If so then the sound is not muted there I have this problem since 12.04 still not resolved Does anyone using Ubuntu have sound ? because so far I hear absolutely nothing...very frustrating

Comment: Ha ha... this post is now long obselete....BIG thanks to everyone who answered me....I received thousands of e-mails over the years....I have no sound problems since I got rid of that M/B....Ubuntu works beautifully for me now...it's just the terminology (language) that confuses me. What do all those terms mean ?  God bless